# Необходимо вывести данные из бд в кортёж python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5, pyqt

Помогите пожалуйста мне нужно создать кортеж и записать в него данные из базы данных, точнее из поля `seat_number` и `room_available`

модуль **main.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView

import mainWindow
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from RoomWindow import Ui_RoomWindow
from lodgers import Ui_lodgers


with sqlite3.connect('baza.db') as db:
    sql = db.cursor()
# room_available (по умолчанию 1 (0- значит койко-место свободно, 1 койко-место занято))
# name ФИО cтудента
# seat number номер конкретного места в секции (1383- место №3 в 138 комнате)
# gender пол студента (1 мужской, 0 женский)

    sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    seat_number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    room_available INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    gender INT NOT NULL
    )""")




# команды подсказки
# INSERT INT users (name, seat_number) VALUES (" "," ")
# SELECT name, seat_number, room_available FROM users (Вывод таблицы вместо
# (name, seat_number, room_available) можно поставить * чтобы вывести всё)
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE (УСЛОВИЕ)



class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.openRoomWindow)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.openlodgers)
        # Функция закрытия главного окна по кнопке Выход
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("section_sketch.png"))


       # self.drowRooms()
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.drowRooms)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)



    # Метод для отрисовки
    def drowRooms(self):
        self.Rooms = []

        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 131 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя через список)
        self.scene.addRect(195, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1311
        self.scene.addRect(240, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  #1312
        self.scene.addRect(195, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  #1313
        self.scene.addRect(240, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  #1314


        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 132 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(330, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1321
        self.scene.addRect(375, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1322
        self.scene.addRect(330, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1323
        self.scene.addRect(375, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1324

        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 133 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(465, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1331
        self.scene.addRect(510, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1332
        self.scene.addRect(465, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1333
        self.scene.addRect(510, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1334

        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 134 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(595, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1341
        self.scene.addRect(640, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1342
        self.scene.addRect(595, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1343
        self.scene.addRect(640, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1344

        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 135 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(595, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1351
        self.scene.addRect(640, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1352
        self.scene.addRect(595, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1353
        self.scene.addRect(640, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1354

        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 136 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(465, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1361
        self.scene.addRect(510, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1362
        self.scene.addRect(465, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1363
        self.scene.addRect(510, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1364

        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 137 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(330, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1371
        self.scene.addRect(375, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1372
        self.scene.addRect(330, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1373
        self.scene.addRect(375, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1374

        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 138 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(195, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1381
        self.scene.addRect(240, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1382
        self.scene.addRect(195, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1383
        self.scene.addRect(240, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1384

        # изменение цвета
        self.Rooms[5][2].setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(Qt.red))




    # Функция перехода на окно Комнаты
    def openRoomWindow(self):
        self.RoomWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_RoomWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self.RoomWindow)
        ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow)
        self.hide()  # для сворачивания предыдущего окна
        self.RoomWindow.show()

    # Функция перехода на окно Проживающие
    def openlodgers(self):
        self.lodgers = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_lodgers()
        ui.setupUi(self.lodgers)
        ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow1)
        sdb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        sdb.setDatabaseName('baza.db')
        sdb.open()
        model = QSqlTableModel(db=sdb)
        model.setTable("residing")
        model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        model.select()
        ui.tableView_1.setModel(model)
        self.hide()  # для сворачивания предыдущего окна
        self.lodgers.show()

    # Функция для возвращения на главное окно (Из окна комнаты) по кнопке Назад
    def returnMainWindow(self):
        self.RoomWindow.close()
        self.show()


    # Функция для возвращения на главное окно (Из окна проживающие) по кнопке Назад
    def returnMainWindow1(self):
        self.lodgers.close()
        self.show()



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

модуль **mainWindow.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1087, 593)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Просмотр Плана Секции")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 530, 161, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 164, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 280, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_8.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 220, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 775, 535))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        '''''
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 0, 71, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        '''''

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(495, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(625, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")


        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(625, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")


        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(495, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")

        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")

        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")



        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комнаты"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Просмотр"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проживающие"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 131"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 132"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 133"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 134"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 135"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 136"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 137"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 138"))
```

модуль **RoomWindow.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'RoomWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_RoomWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, RoomWindow):
        RoomWindow.setObjectName("RoomWindow")
        RoomWindow.resize(1087, 593)
        RoomWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        RoomWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(RoomWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_6.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 551, 411))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        RoomWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(RoomWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(RoomWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, RoomWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        RoomWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("RoomWindow", "Комнаты"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("RoomWindow", "Назад"))
```

модуль **lodgers.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'lodgers.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_lodgers(object):
    def setupUi(self, lodgers):
        lodgers.setObjectName("lodgers")
        lodgers.resize(1087, 593)
        lodgers.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        lodgers.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(lodgers)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_8.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.tableView_1 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 551, 411))
        self.tableView_1.setObjectName("tableView_1")
        lodgers.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(lodgers)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(lodgers)

    def retranslateUi(self, lodgers):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        lodgers.setWindowTitle(_translate("lodgers", "Проживающие"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("lodgers", "Назад"))
```

Comment: опубликуйте  модули `mainWindow.py`, `RoomWindow.py`, `lodgers.py`

Comment: я отредактировал и добавил модули в вопрос

Comment: расскажите лучше, какие действия надо сделать и что должно получиться. Т.е. что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: необходимо создать класс RoomModel в модуле main, и записать туда данные моделей seat_number и room_available, чтобы в дальнейшем реализовать метод в этом классе, который будет отрисовывать квадратики красного и зелёного в зависимости от того занято или свободно место (seat_number соответствует каждому определённому квадратику, если есть запись в базе данных то отрисовывает красный квадратик, если записи нет, то отрисовывается зелёный), мне очень нужно решить эту проблему, могу связаться с Вами где угодно, для дальнейшего обсуждения задачи. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: что-нибудь придумаем, ложитесь спать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень признателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы в строке `sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users`
указали, что таблица `users`, поэтому в строке `model.setTable("users")` поменял `residing` на `users`.
Установите какая у вас, а также поменяете на свои названия `.db` и `.png`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView

#? import mainWindow
import sqlite3

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

#from mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1087, 593)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Просмотр Плана Секции")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 530, 161, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 164, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 280, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_8.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 220, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 775, 535))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
#?        '''''
#?        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
#?        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 0, 71, 21))
#?        font = QtGui.QFont()
#?        font.setPointSize(9)
#?        font.setBold(True)
#?        font.setWeight(75)
#?        self.label.setFont(font)
#?        self.label.setObjectName("label")
#?        '''''

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(495, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(625, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")


        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(625, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")

        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(495, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")

        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")

        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комнаты"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Просмотр"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проживающие"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 131"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 132"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 133"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 134"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 135"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 136"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 137"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 138"))


#from RoomWindow import Ui_RoomWindow
class Ui_RoomWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, RoomWindow):
        RoomWindow.setObjectName("RoomWindow")
        RoomWindow.resize(1087, 593)
        RoomWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        RoomWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(RoomWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_6.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 551, 411))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        RoomWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(RoomWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(RoomWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, RoomWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        RoomWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("RoomWindow", "Комнаты"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("RoomWindow", "Назад"))


#from lodgers import Ui_lodgers
class Ui_lodgers(object):
    def setupUi(self, lodgers):
        lodgers.setObjectName("lodgers")
        lodgers.resize(1087, 593)
        lodgers.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        lodgers.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(lodgers)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_8.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.tableView_1 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 551, 411))
        self.tableView_1.setObjectName("tableView_1")
        lodgers.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(lodgers)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(lodgers)

    def retranslateUi(self, lodgers):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        lodgers.setWindowTitle(_translate("lodgers", "Проживающие"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("lodgers", "Назад"))


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''
# residing
with sqlite3.connect('baza_1214255.db') as db:
    sql = db.cursor()
# room_available (по умолчанию 1 (0- значит койко-место свободно, 1 койко-место занято))
# name           ФИО cтудента
# seat_number    номер конкретного места в секции (1383- место №3 в 138 комнате)
# gender         пол студента (1 мужской, 0 женский)
# 
    sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    seat_number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    room_available INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    gender INT NOT NULL
    )""")

# команды подсказки
# INSERT INT users (name, seat_number) VALUES (" "," ")
# SELECT name, seat_number, room_available FROM users 
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE (УСЛОВИЕ)
'''
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
# это ваш новый класс !!!
class Lodgers(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_lodgers):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Lodgers, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
 
        sdb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        sdb.setDatabaseName('baza_1214255.db')                          # поменяйте
        sdb.open()
        model = QSqlTableModel(db=sdb)
        model.setTable("users")                                      # users  <->   residing   ???
        model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        model.select()
      
        self.tableView_1.setModel(model)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


#class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.openRoomWindow)        
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.openlodgers)           
        # Функция закрытия главного окна по кнопке Выход
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.close)                 
        self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png"))                   # "section_sketch.png"

       # self.drowRooms()
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.drowRooms)             
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.lodgers = Lodgers()                                             # +++
        self.lodgers.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow1)    # +++

        self.rоом_beds = []                                                  # +++
        self.rоом_rect = {                                                   # +++                      
            '131': 0,
            '132': 1,
            '133': 2,
            '134': 3,
            '135': 4,
            '136': 5,
            '137': 6,
            '138': 7,
        }
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
    # Метод для отрисовки
    def drowRooms(self):
        self.Rooms = []
        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 131 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя через список)
        self.scene.addRect(195, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1311
        self.scene.addRect(240, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  #1312
        self.scene.addRect(195, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  #1313
        self.scene.addRect(240, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  #1314
        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 132 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(330, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1321
        self.scene.addRect(375, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1322
        self.scene.addRect(330, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1323
        self.scene.addRect(375, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1324
        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 133 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(465, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1331
        self.scene.addRect(510, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1332
        self.scene.addRect(465, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1333
        self.scene.addRect(510, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1334
        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 134 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(595, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1341
        self.scene.addRect(640, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1342
        self.scene.addRect(595, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1343
        self.scene.addRect(640, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1344
        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 135 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(595, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1351
        self.scene.addRect(640, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1352
        self.scene.addRect(595, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1353
        self.scene.addRect(640, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1354
        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 136 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(465, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1361
        self.scene.addRect(510, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1362
        self.scene.addRect(465, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1363            # !!!
        self.scene.addRect(510, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1364
        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 137 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(330, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1371
        self.scene.addRect(375, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1372
        self.scene.addRect(330, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1373
        self.scene.addRect(375, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1374
        self.Rooms.append((
        # Рисование прямоугольников для 138 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
        self.scene.addRect(195, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1381
        self.scene.addRect(240, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1382
        self.scene.addRect(195, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)), #1383
        self.scene.addRect(240, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)))) #1384

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.rоом_beds = []
        model = self.lodgers.tableView_1.model()
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            if model.data(model.index(row, 2)) == 1:
                rоом_bed = str(model.data(model.index(row, 1)))[:3], str(model.data(model.index(row, 1)))[3]
                self.rоом_beds.append(rоом_bed)

        for k, v  in self.rоом_beds:
#            self.Rooms[5][2].setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(Qt.red))
            self.Rooms[self.rоом_rect[k]][int(v)].setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(Qt.red))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

    # Функция перехода на окно Комнаты
    def openRoomWindow(self):
        self.RoomWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_RoomWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self.RoomWindow)
        ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow)
        self.hide()                                
        self.RoomWindow.show()

    # Функция перехода на окно Проживающие
    def openlodgers(self):                                       
        '''
        self.lodgers = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_lodgers()
        ui.setupUi(self.lodgers)
        ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow1)  
        sdb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        sdb.setDatabaseName('baza_1214255.db')
        sdb.open()
        model = QSqlTableModel(db=sdb)
        model.setTable("users")                              # users     residing   ???
        model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        model.select()
        ui.tableView_1.setModel(model)
        '''
        
        self.hide()                                 
        self.lodgers.show()

    # Функция для возвращения на главное окно (Из окна комнаты) по кнопке Назад
    def returnMainWindow(self):
        self.RoomWindow.close()
        self.show()

    # Функция для возвращения на главное окно (Из окна проживающие) по кнопке Назад
    def returnMainWindow1(self):
        self.lodgers.close()
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @НикитаНефёдов  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @НикитаНефёдов пожалуйста