# Система бронирования номеров в отеле

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

У меня есть два окна, одно для администратора, который может добавлять новые отели/номера и количество мест в них (и другие показатели),  есть окно пользователя в котором пользователь может забронировать данное место. Но я не понимаю как реализовать логику работы, ведь если один пользователь забронировал одно место, то их количество в данном отели должно уменьшится и показывается на одно меньше, плюс как реализовать логику снятия с бронирования, что бы администратор или пользователь могли снять свой (или в случаи с администратором чужой номер).

**Окно пользователя:**

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'to_book.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(660, 470)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox{\n"
"    min-width:  640px;\n"
"    max-width: 640px;\n"
"    min-height: 419px;\n"
"    max-height: 419px;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 642, 421))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_5, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 660, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_3)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Варианты номеров"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "__"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Изображение"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Адрес"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во мест"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Цена за ночь"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Свобод. места"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Оценка"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Забронировать"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Отменить бронь"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить изменения"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Главное"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Профиль пользователя"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выйти"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Окно администратора:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'to_book_admin.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(660, 469)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox{\n"
"    min-width:  640px;\n"
"    max-width: 640px;\n"
"    min-height: 419px;\n"
"    max-height: 419px;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 642, 421))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_5, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 660, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_3)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Варианты номеров"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "__"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Изображение"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Адрес"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во мест"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Цена за ночь"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Свобод. места"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Оценка"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить обьявление"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить обьявление"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить изменения"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Главное"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Профиль администратора"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выйти"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Учите БД. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1217490 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214255 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+sqlite3 . ...

Comment: @S.Nick в данных примерах не понятна работа БД из-за специфики проекта.

Comment: Странные вы вещи говорите. БД используются в миллионах приложений. Но вот ваше имеет особую "специфику". Таким образом, что-бы понять, как учесть эту "специфику" надо понимать в чем именно она заключается. Хотите помощи -  изложите ваш видение.  Либо.... учить БД.  Ибо специфики нет, а есть непонимание принципов работы БД.  Последнее -  наиболее вероятно.

Comment: @passant я имел ввиду то, что я не понимаю приведенные примеры из-за большого объёма кода и нескольких файлов. Может для вас это и легко, но мне как новичку не понятно как работает БД на таком примере.